# Django template error: could not parse the remainder

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I am trying to render a value from a dict in the Django(1.6.11) template. unit_list is list of unit(model). unit.unit_id is the primary key of unit. tags_dict is dict of tags with unit_ids as keys and tags as values.

```
{% for unit in unit_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ unit.unit_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ unit.version }}</td>
    <td>{{ unit.release_dt|date:'Y-m-d' }} {{ unit.release_dt|time:'H:i:s' }}</td>
    <td>{{ unit.update_dt|date:'Y-m-d' }} {{ unit.update_dt|time:'H:i:s' }}</td>
    <td>
        {{ tags_dict[unicode(unit)] }}
    </td>
    <td>{{ unit.last_modified|date:'Y-m-d' }} {{ unit.last_modified|time:'H:i:s' }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But I got this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(unicode(unit))' from 'tags_dict.get(unicode(unit))'
```

Comment: Does this error go away if you remove the `unicode` call on `unit`?

Comment: then the error was using '(unit)'. I guess I will just have to remove method call with () in templates

Comment: Yes, `unicode` is a built in function, but it doesn't work inside the `{{` and `}}`  - that's why it's failing.

Comment: You could use a template tag for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can’t put function calls like this into a Django template. It looks like you should do this in your view and pass it to the template as a variable. You could also add a method on the unit class, like this:

```
def get_tags(self):
    tags_dict = {} # TODO: retrieve tags dict.
    return tags_dict[unicode(self)]
```

Then, you could do something like this in your template: `{{ unit.get_tags }}`.

Comment: This might not be the best suited solution, as the dict would have to be built on every iteration. A templatetag would be a much more suited solution

Comment: @karthikr I meant that the dict could be retrieved from somewhere, not created every time. See edit.

Comment: Sure, but how would that retrieval happen ? Since it is a tag dictionary, it would have to be retrieved dynamically. Since you already have this is context, why not leverage it? I am not saying this wont work. All I am saying is, it is more efficient to have a `simple_tag`. Your thoughts ?

Comment: @karthikr You are correct. However, it is hard to tell how the OP gets the tag dictionary, so we don’t know how complex it is to create.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the blank spaces like this:

```
<td>{{unit.last_modified|date:'Y-m-d'}}{{unit.last_modified|time:'H:i:s'}}</td>
```

Comment: Yep! No need to do what the marked answer suggested. This is the problem if you have spaces.